# Text filtering with shell scripting

Tags: shell, text, awk, scripting, grep

I am really finding it hard to filter some text using shell scripting.
Basically, I am logging into several network devices and I find their directly connected neighbors.  I then export these results in a .txt file, which looks like this:

```
    Host IP: 175.334.2.43

-------------------------
Device ID: first_device
Entry address(es):
  IP address: 323.43.5.32
Platform: cisco 428,  Capabilities: Router Switch IGMP
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/3,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/10
Holdtime : 130 sec


advertisement version: 2
Protocol Hello:  OUI=0x0fsdfs0C, Protocol ID=0x0fdf2; payload len=27, value=0dsgfjhb2CAE00FF0000
VTP Management Domain: ''
Native VLAN: 453
Duplex: full
Management address(es):
  IP address: 323.43.5.32

-------------------------
Device ID: second_device
Entry address(es):
  IP address: 323.43.5.398
Platform: cisco 428,  Capabilities: Router Switch IGMP
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/5,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/123
Holdtime : 130 sec


advertisement version: 2
Protocol Hello:  OUI=0x0fsdfs0C, Protocol ID=0x0fdf2; payload len=27, value=0dsgfjhb2CAE00FF0000
VTP Management Domain: ''
Native VLAN: 453
Duplex: full
Management address(es):
  IP address: 323.43.5.398

Host IP: 342.52.5.2

-------------------------
Device ID: third_device
Entry address(es):
  IP address: 32.43.15.32
Platform: cisco 428,  Capabilities: Router Switch IGMP
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/98,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/165
Holdtime : 130 sec


advertisement version: 2
Protocol Hello:  OUI=0x0fsdfs0C, Protocol ID=0x0fdf2; payload len=27, value=0dsgfjhb2CAE00FF0000
VTP Management Domain: ''
Native VLAN: 453
Duplex: full
Management address(es):
  IP address: 32.43.15.32

-------------------------
Device ID: fourth_device
Entry address(es):
  IP address: 0832.54.254.6
Platform: cisco 428,  Capabilities: Router Switch IGMP
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/543,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/16
Holdtime : 130 sec


advertisement version: 2
Protocol Hello:  OUI=0x0fsdfs0C, Protocol ID=0x0fdf2; payload len=27, value=0dsgfjhb2CAE00FF0000
VTP Management Domain: ''
Native VLAN: 453
Duplex: full
Management address(es):
  IP address: 0832.54.254.6
```

I want to filter this file and organize it in columns. I do this using the filter_res.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e '/Management address(es):/{N;d;}' results.txt >results2.txt
grep "Host IP:" results2.txt | awk  '{print $3}' >host_ip.txt
grep "Device ID:.*" results2.txt | awk '{print $3 ","}' >dev_ids.txt
grep "IP address: " results2.txt | awk '{print $3 ","}' >cpe_ip.txt
grep "Platform: " results2.txt | awk '{print $2 $3}' >chassis.txt
grep "Interface:" results2.txt >interfaces.txt
awk '{print $7}' interfaces.txt >cpe_int.txt
awk '{print $2}' interfaces.txt >agg_int.txt
pr -mts' ' dev_ids.txt cpe_ip.txt chassis.txt agg_int.txt cpe_int.txt >final_results.txt
```

The final_results.txt is OK, except that I would like to append one last column at the end, with the **host_ip** for each line. This is the result I have:

```
first_device, 323.43.5.32, cisco428, GigabitEthernet0/3, GigabitEthernet0/10
second_device, 323.43.5.398, cisco428, GigabitEthernet0/5, GigabitEthernet0/123
third_device, 32.43.15.32, cisco428, GigabitEthernet0/98, GigabitEthernet0/165
fourth_device, 0832.54.254.6, cisco428, GigabitEthernet0/543, GigabitEthernet0/16
```

What I would like would be:

```
first_device, 323.43.5.32, cisco428, GigabitEthernet0/3, GigabitEthernet0/10, 175.334.2.43
second_device, 323.43.5.398, cisco428, GigabitEthernet0/5, GigabitEthernet0/123, 175.334.2.43
third_device, 32.43.15.32, cisco428, GigabitEthernet0/98, GigabitEthernet0/165, 342.52.5.2
fourth_device, 0832.54.254.6, cisco428, GigabitEthernet0/543, GigabitEthernet0/16, 342.52.5.2
```

Comment: What happened when you added `host_ip.txt` to the list of column files to the `pr` command?

Comment: If I add it, the host IP's don't appear at their correct position They should be repeated for each of their connected devices.

Comment: `I am really finding it hard to filter some text using shell scripting.` - that makes perfect since since that's not what shell scripting is for. Shell scripting is for manipulating files and processes and sequencing calls to tools. Awk scripting is for manipulating text so in UNIX if you need to filter (or otherwise manipulate) text the shell just calls awk to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need all these intermediate steps, rather combine them in one `awk` script.  Here is a hacky way of doing it, not recommended for long term use but perhaps you can use as a starting point...

```
$ awk -v RS="[-]+\n" -v c=',' '
              NR>1{print $3 c,$8 c,$10$11,$17,$22 c,hip} 
        /Host IP:/{hip=$NF}' file


first_device, 323.43.5.32, cisco428, GigabitEthernet0/3, GigabitEthernet0/10, 175.334.2.43
second_device, 323.43.5.398, cisco428, GigabitEthernet0/5, GigabitEthernet0/123, 175.334.2.43
third_device, 32.43.15.32, cisco428, GigabitEthernet0/98, GigabitEthernet0/165, 342.52.5.2
fourth_device, 0832.54.254.6, cisco428, GigabitEthernet0/543, GigabitEthernet0/16, 342.52.5.2
```

ps. Need `gawk` due to multi-char RS specification.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: please accept this as the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: No need to put the `-` in a bracket expression,it has no special meaning in a regexp UNLESS it's put in a bracket expression. You should mention it's gawk-specific due to the multi-char RS though.

Comment: @Ed Morton, yes I know but `-+` looks funny. `[-]` is valid regex since it's not specifying a range.  Added gawk only note.